# How to set up docker in Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to connect to docker from within Jenkins. I also downloaded the plugins related to docker. But somehow the docker connection was not provided. What could be the reason for this?
First of all, I am working on windows operating system.
I have installed docker.
I ran Jenkins in docker.
I created my github repo.
I wrote script pipeline in jenkins.
m2 files appear to have been created on my computer.
I downloaded maven and docker inside tools in Jenkins.
Docker : I gave the extension of the docker.exe file on my computer but it didn't work.
Docker : I did docker and latest but it didn't work.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y405O.png)

[my jenkins_home file and workspace my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0yQi.png)

I also don't know why the @temp file occurs in the 2nd picture. What could be the reason for this?
I also added docker file to my projects.

Answer (score 1):

Solved Question : Let's run the commands in order;

1.

```bash
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

2. 

```bash
docker exec -it --user root <container id> bash
```

3. 

```bash
curl https://get.docker.com/ > dockerinstall && chmod 777 dockerinstall && ./dockerinstall
```

4. 

```bash
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

5. 

```bash
docker exec -it <container id> bash
cat var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```